# Why am I being denied when I change my user agent?

Tags: http, go, request

I have a simple request to get the robots.txt file from nike.com. A normal GET request in Go returns the file as expected. In my current browser (Chrome) I can access the file fine. However, when I try to change my UA in Go to the same as that of my browser, I get a 403 error.

In other words, I can access the page using the default settings in Go, proving that my code is correct, but once I change the UA I get a 403 (even though that same UA in my browser works).

If I change the UA to something random (e.g. "Not me") then I get a 200. Why can't I use my browser's UA?

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
)

func main() {
    var resp *http.Response
    var err error
    u := "http://www.nike.com/robots.txt"

    for _, ua := range []bool{false, true} {
        client := &http.Client{}
        req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", u, nil)
        if ua == true {
            req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36")
        }
        resp, err = client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
        log.Println("StatusCode", resp.StatusCode)
        spew.Dump(resp.Request)
        log.Println("----------------------------")
    }

}
```

The response:

```
2016/06/22 16:56:57 StatusCode 200
(*http.Request)(0xc8200d02a0)({
 Method: (string) (len=3) "GET",
 URL: (*url.URL)(0xc820076280)(http://www.nike.com/robots.txt),
 Proto: (string) (len=8) "HTTP/1.1",
 ProtoMajor: (int) 1,
 ProtoMinor: (int) 1,
 Header: (http.Header) {
 },
 Body: (io.ReadCloser) <nil>,
 ContentLength: (int64) 0,
 TransferEncoding: ([]string) <nil>,
 Close: (bool) false,
 Host: (string) (len=12) "www.nike.com",
 Form: (url.Values) <nil>,
 PostForm: (url.Values) <nil>,
 MultipartForm: (*multipart.Form)(<nil>),
 Trailer: (http.Header) <nil>,
 RemoteAddr: (string) "",
 RequestURI: (string) "",
 TLS: (*tls.ConnectionState)(<nil>),
 Cancel: (<-chan struct {}) <nil>
})
2016/06/22 16:56:57 ----------------------------
2016/06/22 16:56:57 StatusCode 403
(*http.Request)(0xc820110000)({
 Method: (string) (len=3) "GET",
 URL: (*url.URL)(0xc8200ea180)(http://www.nike.com/robots.txt),
 Proto: (string) (len=8) "HTTP/1.1",
 ProtoMajor: (int) 1,
 ProtoMinor: (int) 1,
 Header: (http.Header) (len=1) {
  (string) (len=10) "User-Agent": ([]string) (len=1 cap=1) {
   (string) (len=104) "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36"
  }
 },
 Body: (io.ReadCloser) <nil>,
 ContentLength: (int64) 0,
 TransferEncoding: ([]string) <nil>,
 Close: (bool) false,
 Host: (string) (len=12) "www.nike.com",
 Form: (url.Values) <nil>,
 PostForm: (url.Values) <nil>,
 MultipartForm: (*multipart.Form)(<nil>),
 Trailer: (http.Header) <nil>,
 RemoteAddr: (string) "",
 RequestURI: (string) "",
 TLS: (*tls.ConnectionState)(<nil>),
 Cancel: (<-chan struct {}) <nil>
})
2016/06/22 16:56:57 ----------------------------
```

EDIT: 
I've been playing around a bit and if I set ALL the other headers that Chrome sends then it works.

Comment: Interesting! User agent of just "Chrome" gives 403. User agent of "chrome" gives 200. Perhaps nike thinks you're trying to impersonate a browser?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your test code uses the same HTTP client object to send both requests, which presumably both go over the same connection.

Did you try sending the requests on different connections?  Try setting your flags to true then false and see if it's always just the second one that fails.

Comment: I tried switching the order w/ no luck. I've been playing around a bit and if I set ALL the other headers that Chrome sends then it works. Wondering why Nike does that...

Comment: @kristen: the site is attempting to prevent malicious activity. If it knows you're not a chrome browser, but gets a chrome user agent, it will deny the request.

Comment: that was my next suggestion - to review all other headers.  There must be some kind of fingerprinting going on.  It's quite common for the UA string to look very similar between different clients.

Comment: @JimB: that makes sense. I was going crazy trying to see if it was some sort of bug in Go or what not. Doesn't seem like a good way to prevent anything, since even an amateur like myself could (eventually) figure out that setting the rest of the headers lets me spoof a real browser.

Comment: @kristen: I didn't say it was very good at doing that ;) It's most likely an application firewall that applies various heuristics to each request based on previous patterns (it is going through an akamai edge server). If you were to  cause "problems" with a different particular pattern of headers, you may find that blocked too.  Regardless the behavior is entirely up to the remote server.